# Strip Javascript on(whatever) events from Code using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, sanitization

I want to strip out all JavaScript from a small snippet (4-6 lines) of HTML, I've read on here before that its best not to use REGEX on HTML, so if anybody knows a better way, please advise.

So for example i have the following code:

```
<a href="go/to/my/link" onclick="fetchMeSomeData(this)">My Link</a>
<p onfocus="doSomethingAmazing();"></p>
```

Now in PHP i want to replace the on(what ever event it is) event with just an empty space.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library to strip things like JavaScript and plugins from the code.  It's much better then a blacklist-based regex approach because it uses a full HTML parser and a whitelist to clean the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I've build such regexp some time ago, looks a bit scary though :). Here is pure regexp, you might need to additionally mask special chars to match your language requirements.

```
(\son[a-z]+\s*=\s*"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"(?=[^<]*?>))|(\son[a-z]+\s*=\s*'[^'\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^'\\\r\n]*)*'(?=[^<]*?>))
```

Here is masked version (according to java standards), that you should be able to use as a string.

```
(\\son[a-z]+\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\\\r\\n]*)*\"(?=[^<]*?>))|(\\son[a-z]+\\s*=\\s*'[^'\\\\\\r\\n]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\\\r\\n]*)*'(?=[^<]*?>))
```

It looks only inside tags and takes into consideration masked quotes inside events. I'm sure it is not 100% bullet proof though.